# After updating the microsoft sdk to 6.5 professional, an "Windows Mobile 6.5 Device" on platform list

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

After I installed the latest SDKs I found related to Windows Mobile 6.5, does not appear an "Windows Mobile 6.5 Device" in the plataform list.

This is normal? If not what should be the needed installs. The SDKs were installed on a clean Windows XP virtual machine since the application must be also compiled to PPC2003 (which is the setting on the host machine).

Any ideas?

Edit: It's on deploy list. It never brings an WinMo 6.5 Device, just emulatores. It only brings an WinMo Pro 6 device.

Comment: With what version of Visual Studio?  And which platform list, exactly (the output for your app, the "deploy to" list, the "target platform" list when creating a new app, something else?)

Comment: A reboot of your PC may be required after installing the SDK. Like Chris hinted to, I think WM6.5 may require VS2008 (not higher).

Comment: The list of devices to Deploy, @ctacke.

Comment: I see the VS2008 tag now. Thanks Fabricio. Did the reboot do any good on your Virtual Machine?

Comment: I retagged to show that I'm using VS2008, @jp2code

Comment: No. I rebooted a fez times since install, but it never brings an WinMobile 6.5 Device option, only emulators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install and use WM6.5 target you need to have VS2008 Pro or better (remeain in the VS2008 chain, no VS2010 or 2012); VS2008 SP1 installed; WM6 SDK installed and finally WM6.5 DTK (developer toolkit).

See also wm65 requirements at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5389

excerpt:
 - Microsoft .NET Compact Framework v2 SP2.
 - Important: "Visual C++ Smart Device Programmability", an option of
   Microsoft Visual Studio Setup, must be selected and installed during
   Visual Studio installation.